# Datagrab stuck/fail on 90% 4/5

Tags: datagrab, import

Been using dataGrab for a new site, to import stuff that’s exported to a Json-file from a PIM-system.
All good, working like a charm.

Yesterday, we tried triggering the remote URL, with only 5 entries to be imported: It returned the page that says import done. But when going to the datagrab-plugin-page, it’s stuck at 4/5, and saying “running”.

This prevents me from trying it manually. If I try triggering it manually,  I get the same “Import success”-page, but it’s stuck.
And the logs return “A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()”.

So, my question is, any way of stopping the session?
Also, any idea of why it’s messing with me like this all of a sudden? :)

Running EE 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Posting here to help others in the same spot.

I had the batch field set to 500/batch, since we did huge imports at the start. Got the problem when we started importing <500 I guess.

So, I removed the 500 from the input field, and now it works like it's supposed to.

Sweet!